# Volume of intersection of two partial spheres in spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, geometry, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

Assume I have one partial sphere $s_1$ defined by center $c_1: (x_1, y_1, z_1)$, radius: $\rho_1$, polar angle: $\phi_{1, min} \leq \phi_1 \leq \phi_{1, max}$, and azimuthal angle: $\theta_{1, min} \leq \theta_1 \leq \theta_{1, max}$. I have another partial sphere $s_2$ defined by center $c_2: (x_2, y_2, z_2)$, radius: $\rho_2$, $\phi_{2, min} \leq \phi_2 \leq \phi_{2, max}$, $\theta_{2, min} \leq \rho_2 \leq \theta_{2, max}$.

Assume I also know the $4 \times 4$ transformation matrix $T$ that maps any point in the coordinate frame of $s_1$ to the coordinate frame of $s_2$.

I would like to find the volume of intersection of these two spheres. Using this answer and this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605861/volume-between-spheres-spherical-coordinates) and this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/705935/find-volume-between-two-spheres-using-cylindrical-spherical-coordinates), I'm confused as to whether to convert to cylindrical coordinates and then try to integrate over $z$, $r$, and $\theta$ or go to cartesian coordinates and try to integrate over $x$, $y$ and $z$, or just stick to spherical coordinates and integrate over $\rho, \theta, \phi$.

Additionally, to clarify per the comments, in order to set the bounds of the integration correctly, I think I need to use $T$ as applied to the min/max azimuthal and polar angles? The angles are measured with respect to the z-axis of each sphere's respective coordinate frame as in this [picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#/media/File:3D_Spherical_2.svg) from the wikipedia entry on [spherical coordinate conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system).

Thanks!

Comment: The problem, more than the choice of spherical or cylindrical coordinates, is to describe both spheres in the same coordinate system. Let's pick the first sphere as the reference. For example, we can always shift the center $c_1$ to the origin and using $c_2=(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1,c_2-c_1)$, and then apply a rotation to have both sphere centers in one reference axis. The work comes when describing the second sphere (min/max aximuthal/polar angles) in the new global coordinate system. Without this consideration there is little to say about the convenience of spherical, cylindrical, or Cartesian.

Comment: Thanks @cjferes edited per your comments. Hopefully that clarifies.

Comment: Thanks. I assume that this is a re-post of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4735175/volume-of-intersection-of-two-partial-spheres-having-origins-at-different-coordi). How are the angular limits of each round bottomed cone defined, as in, what are the axis used to define the polar and azimuth angles of each solid?  Don't want to assume something wrong.

Comment: Yes @cjferes hopefully this post gets an answer / is more clear. The polar and azimuthal angles are relative to the z-axis of the sphere's coordinate frame as in this picture from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#/media/File:3D_Spherical_2.svg. Also added this to the original post, thank you for the clarifications.